How to find the angle of an ellipse's semi-major axis given a rectangle with known width and height, and tangent to the ellipse on 4 sides?
Given a rectangle that contains an ellipse, and the ellipse is tangent on all 4 sides, how can I find the angle and lengths of the semi-major and semi-minor axes? I'm mainly interested in getting the angle, as I think I can work out the lengths once I have that.
The width and height of the rectangle is known. The center of the ellipse is the same as the center of the rectangle. The quadrant relative to the center of the ellipse that the semi-major axis falls in is known. The tangent points are known.


I doubt you have sufficient information to determine the angle.
Consider these four ellipses and their axes in the same rectangle.


@idon'tknowwhatiamdoing - when I first saw the question it said "I have another version of this problem which also has the tangent points"

Let the problem be: Given a rectangle with known dimensions, how to inscribe a tangent ellipse to the four sides, such that the semi-mayor angle is given?
An ellipse with semi axes $\{a,b\}$ centered at the origin and with an semi-mayor angle of $\theta$ can be described as
$$
\mathscr{E}\to a (x \sin\theta+y \cos\theta)^2+b (x \cos\theta-y \sin\theta)^2+a b f=0
$$
This ellipse should be tangent to $x = \pm x_1$ and $y= \pm y_1$ the rectangle sides, so we have
$$
\cases{
 a (x_1 \sin\theta+y \cos\theta)^2+b (x_1 \cos\theta-y \sin\theta)^2+a b f=p_1(y)\\
a (x \sin\theta+y_1 \cos\theta)^2+b (x \cos\theta-y_1 \sin\theta)^2+a b f=p_2(x)
}
$$
and due to tangency we have
$$
\cases{
p_1(y) = c_1(y-r_1)^2\\
p_2(x) = c_2(x-r_2)^2
}\ \ \ \ \forall \{x,y\}
$$
which is equivalent to
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 a b f+x_1^2 \left(a \sin^2\theta+b \cos^2\theta\right)-c_1 r_1^2 & = & 0\\
 x_1 (a-b) \sin (2 \theta )+2 c_1 r_1 & = & 0 \\
 a \cos^2\theta+b \sin^2\theta-c_1 & = & 0 \\
 a b f+y_1^2 \left(a \cos^2\theta+b \sin^2\theta\right)-c_2 r_2^2 & = & 0 \\
 y_1 (a-b) \sin (2 \theta )+2 c_2 r_2 & = & 0 \\
 a \sin^2\theta+b \cos^2\theta-c_2 & = & 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$
an additional condition is required: $a b > 0$ so we follow with
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{rcl}
 a b f+x_1^2 \left(a \sin ^2\theta+b \cos^2\theta\right)-c_1 r_1^2 & = & 0\\
 x_1 (a-b) \sin (2 \theta )+2 c_1 r_1 & = & 0 \\
 a \cos^2\theta+b \sin^2\theta-c_1 & = & 0 \\
 a b f+y_1^2 \left(a \cos^2\theta+b \sin^2\theta\right)-c_2 r_2^2 & = & 0 \\
 y_1 (a-b) \sin (2 \theta )+2 c_2 r_2 & = & 0 \\
 a \sin^2\theta+b \cos^2\theta-c_2 & = & 0\\
a b - 1 & = & 0
\end{array}
\right.
$$
Now solving for $\{a,b,f,c_1,c_2,r_1,r_2\}$ we are done.
Follows an example with $\{x_1=5, y_1 = 3.5,\theta = -0.51257\}$ giving $\{a=1.10388, b=0.226474, f=-28\}$

and another one for $\{x_1 = 3,y_1 = 2, \theta=\frac{\pi}{3}\}$ giving $\left\{a=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{3}{23}}}{2},b=\frac{\sqrt{\frac{23}{3}}}{2},f=-\sqrt{69}\right\}$

Note that in this case, the solution considered the minor semi-axis due to the impossibility concerning the mayor-axis.
